# google colab python3 name cv2 is not defined

Tags: python, opencv, google-colaboratory

I imported all the required libraries and tried to do a simple image reconginition program with opencv but the error cv2 not defined shows up but as it is visible from the first cell that open cv is installed and no import errors are shown as I have already done the !apt updates and the version I have is 3.4.0. Any help on the program attached below would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: You probably did not run the first cell... the one with the `import cv2`

Comment: Hey, thanks for the reply but without running the first cell I cud have never uploaded the watch.jpg image. Regardless I did run both the cells again and the error stays. Any further help would be appreciated. Like I said I even updated numpy and even both the opencv sudo apt updates and it still says cv2 is not defined.

Comment: Just add `import cv2` in the same cell (right before `img = cv2.imread(...)`) and let us know what happens. BTW, why did you use the `opencv3.0` tag if you apparently want to use the newest version?

Comment: Hey, Thanks for your suggestion. I did try that out and there seems to be some kind of improvement but its still not working. It says it crashes during runtime. Please have a look at this and let me if know how to fix this. 
https://i.imgur.com/f74IJlE.png

Comment: I posted an answer with an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). If you find it useful, consider upvoting or marking as answer.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! This was really useful and I was able to finally make it work. My Main reason for switching to google colab was because I wasn't able to install tensorflow on my Jupyter notebook coz of my pc reqs. I will upvote and mark as answer as soon as I reach 15 reputation points coz this site doesn't allow me to do so otherwise but thanks a lot for your help, was very useful :).

Answer (score 7):

First, I recommend you to get yourself familiar with Jupyter notebooks and how they work. Then, the first problem you had it was because you were trying to run a cell that uses `cv2` without running the `import cv2` before. The second problem you are facing is because you cannot use `cv2.imshow(...)`, since it requires an X server which is not available. Below, you can see an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in which you can upload an image, use OpenCV to read and change it, and display images:

```py
import cv2
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
# %matplotlib inline

from google.colab import files
uploaded = files.upload()

img = cv2.imread('lenna.png')
gray_img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(ncols=2)

ax[0].imshow(img[..., ::-1])  # BGR to RGB
ax[0].set_title('Original image')

ax[1].imshow(gray_img, cmap=plt.cm.gray)
ax[1].set_title('Grayscale image')

plt.show()
```

If you run on Google Colab, it will look like this:

[image: colab example]

Answer (score 3):

You can use this solution if you're using google colab:

```
from google.colab.patches import cv2_imshow

image = cv2.imread('image.png')

cv2_imshow( image)

cv2.waitKey(0)

cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: try to change the path of the image

Comment: this is even worse. it lacks the `import` entirely, so `cv2` **can't** possibly be defined. that's how to cause the error in the question.